# Qual a diferença entre SaveDialog e FileSaveDialog no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, embarcadero

Já usei ambos os componentes, tanto o SaveDialog quanto o FileSaveDialog para as mesmas tarefas, sem notar nenhuma diferença entre os mesmos, exceto o fato do FileSaveDialog não ser compatível com o Windows XP, a coexistência dos dois componentes foi penas um capricho da Embarcadero ou eles possuem utilidades diferenciadas entre si?

Comment: Procurei na documentação do Delphi e encontrei apenas o SaveDialog. Em qual versão o TFileSaveDialog se encontra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diferença é que `TSaveDialog` usa janelas padrões e `TFileSaveDialog` usa o visual do Vista.

Conforme o site http://docs.embarcadero.com as seguintes informações:

### TSaveDialog

`TSaveDialog` mostra uma janela de dialogo modal para selecionar o nome do arquivo e salva-lo. A janela de diálogo não aparece durante a execução até que ele é ativado por uma chamada para o método de execução.

Quando o usuário clica em Salvar a janela de dialogo fecha e salva o nome do arquivo na propriedade `FileName`.

`TSaveDialog` é estendido de `TOpenDialog` que é estendido de `TCommomDialog`

### TFileSaveDialog

É uma classe para o estilo de janelas do Vista. Está classe é estendida de `TCustomFileSaveDialog`, isto permite criar janelas com o estilo do Windows Vista com `CLSID_FileSaveDialog` e implementa a interface do `IFileSaveDialog`

`TFileSaveDialog` é estendida de `TCustomFileSaveDialog` que é estendido de `TCustomFileDialog`.

### TCustomFileDialog

Janela de para abrir e salvar arquivos, está classe base abstrata estende para as janelas de dialogo de arquivo para o estilo do Microsoft Windows Vista.

**Nota:** Nas novas versões do *Delphi* você pode usar `TSaveDialog`, pois aparentemente ele detecta o sistema operacional e troca para o sistema de janelas do mesmo.

Comment: Então tudo se resume a aparências?

Comment: @EvertonBruno acredito que seja mais do que aparencia, o sistema de janelas do vista em diante tem botões e algumas funções a mais, note que parece que nas novas versões do Delphi funções como `TSaveDialog` já detectam o sistema e usam o sistema de janelas do sistema operacional atual, dando compatibilidade assim para sistemas mais antigos (acredito eu).

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, também desconhecia e não tinha conseguido encontrar na documentação.